# GWT Widget borders not showing up properly

Tags: css, eclipse, gwt

I'm working on a GWT project and I'm working with code that was already written by a coworker. I see that on some pages of the website, some widgets (ListBox, TextBox, etc) have their borders missing. I initially thought it was because he was setting the exact pixels for these widgets, but when I opened the GWT Designer in Eclipse and created a brand new ListBox, the border missing issue was still there, which makes me think it's not because of pixels being set exactly.

Here is a screen shot of the designer:

[image: GWT Designer Capture]

As you can see, the right border on the Description textbox is missing, along with the top border of both ListBoxes.

Please help!

Comment: Just open this in a browser, play with the css styles and you will get it fixed! Then change the style in the code as well.

Comment: Inspect the CSS of the widgets with a web inspector (Mozilla Firebug, Safari Web Inspector, Chrome DevTools, Opera DragonFly or Internet Explorer Developer Tools) to see why the top border is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

In your css file add this

```
select {
    border-top:1px solid #CCC;
}
```